# GeneralException if cell being edited

Tags: excel, ms-office, office365, office-js

I have some js code in Excel addin that works fine while no cell in edit mode. But if there's a cell being edited the call to context.sync() will fail with GeneralException 'Invalid API call in the current context.'

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        //this line enough to fail 
        return ctx.sync();
    }).catch(function (error) {

    })
```

Is there any way to 'release' the cell from js?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that edit-mode makes any API call fail is a "known-issue", and is not really fixable -- even VBA exhibits that same problem for [most] of API calls.

That said, the idea of having a JS method that will explicitly un-cell-edit is an interesting thought.  My only worry is whether that will always correspond to the users' intention, even if it always corresponds to what a developer feels like they'd like to have.  I'll run it by our team, though I think the best way to track this is via an "official" suggestion that you can file here:  https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

At the very least, we could get a more helpful error message and/or a specific error code.  Again, let me discuss it with the team.

Comment: Thank you. In VBA world it was possible to disable editing for entire application before starting the script and turn it back after or change focus to menu item. I hoped there were hacks like that for JS as well.

Comment: Michael, as this question was raised in july, is there any update on this. also i can see this issue only on excel client in surface pro, is there any specific reason for it

Comment: By the way:  assuming that you are using the latest JavaScript files from the CDN, the error code and message should now be much clearer (and have, for the past few months). If that is not the case, please let me know...